# Using Arrays in email template in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am passing an array in template parameters in Magento's `sendNewOrderEmail` function as:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $this,
                'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
                'sa'           => $someArray  // This is an array
            )
        );
```

But I am not able to use the variable `sa` in the magento email template. I tried using it like `{{var sa}}` But in the email i get `Array` instead of the contents.
How can I display contents of the array in the email.

Comment: It depends on what you need. F.e. you can encode it. `... => json_encode($someArray);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `sa.key` where key is key in array.

Or you can merge this array with base params array

Comment: It is array with numeric indices. $someArray[0]...
How to use key in this? How to merge with base params array? sorry, I am new to magento

Comment: @Sourabh then try rewrite this array before insert to template. Change numeric keys to keys with prefix. `foreach($someArray AS $key=>$value) { $params["keys".$key] = $value; }`

Comment: it will generate keys as key0, key1..etc. But how will i know which keys to use, because each time no. of elements in array can differ. Is there a way by which we can loop through array in magento's email template?

Comment: @Sourabh You can try include block. There is example: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/is-there-a-way-to-add-foreach-loop-in-email-template Or you can generate HTML block in PHP and insert it to template. This is not very correct way, but is fast solution.